# How do I measure the similarity of two bivariate time series?

Tags: statistics, information-theory, machine-learning

Suppose I have two bivariate time series:

$$ ts1 = [<a_1, b_1>, <a_2, b_2>, \cdots, <a_N, b_N>] $$

$$ ts2 = [<c_1, d_2>, <c_2, d_2>, \cdots, <c_N, d_N>] $$

Which metrics can I use to measure the "similarity" of $ts1$ and $ts2$? And which test can I use to determine if the "similarity" is significant or not?

Comment: Here's an equivalent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723157/how-to-compare-two-curves-arrays-of-points. The metric you choose, however, will depend on your application.

Comment: what kind of features do you consider similar?